# Get code example from msdn.microsoft

Tags: vsto, msdn

When i try to download the code from this page: [Deploying Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the Office System SE Solutions Using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332051.aspx) 
I just get an page saying "We are sorry, the request page could not be found".
How do I get the code?

Btw. i am clicking the link that says:
Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition Sample: Deploying Office Solutions Using Windows Installer Version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request page doesn't exist, there frankly isn't anything we can do about it. You could send their support an e-mail to inform them of this problem though. :)